# Every combination from given characters from given minimum length to maximum

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, permutation

i know there was some questions similar to this one but i couldn't find answer exactly on this problem or come up with solution so here i am.

I have a task that says:

> Users should be able to define how long the string will be (min and max length), specify possible chars of string (from what characters string should be made) and how much strings he wants.

So i almost finished it but there is one main problem with Min and Max length of String. From what i understand when user put for example `minLength = 2, maxLength = 5` it should print all combination with 2 characters, 3, 4 and 5.

I would like to know what statement should i put in my code to work as it should. For now my code looks like this

```
  private void iterate(char[] chars, int maxLength, int minLength, int howMany, char[] build, int pos) {
        while (check < howMany) {

            if (pos == maxLength || ????) { // what to do here
                Word word = new Word(null, new String(build));
                SetOfWords.add(word);
                save(word);
                check++;
                return;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
                build[pos] = chars[i];
                iterate(chars, maxLength, minLength, howMany, build, pos + 1);
            }
        }
    }
```

And when i pass let's say 4 as a maxLength it generates all combination but with only 4 characters like this.

```
 {
        "id": 1,
        "word": "aaaa"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "word": "aaad"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "word": "aaab"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "word": "aaac"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "word": "aaba"
    }
]
```

I want it to generate all possibilities from 1 character to 5 and then eventually set lower limit.

Comment: Generating *all* possibilities in order to return a small sample is a really bad idea. Even with small values of the parameters, the full list of possibilities can be enormous. For example, if you want strings of length 6 from the alphabet consisting of upper and lower case letters and digits, you will produce 56,800,235,584 strings. If all you needed was eight of them, you will have unnecessarily produced 56,800,235,576 strings, which is going to take a noticeable amount of time (and quite possibly blow up your memory while it tries to store them).

Comment: Actually i dont want to make all possible strings from alphabet, im passing String and later converting it to char array and I'm creating permutations of string from given chars so in example i passed "abcd"